# What does scipy Rotation.apply?

Tags: python, scipy

following Problem:

I have

- a 3x3 Rotation Matrix R that describes the rotation between:
- my Nx3 Points A
- and my Nx3 Points B

Now I want to transform the Points A to B.

Now using scipy Rotation apply I get a different solution compared to doing it by hand:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

# With scipy
R_scipy = Rotation.from_dcm(R)
B_scipy = R_scipy.apply(A)

# By hand
B_hand = (R.dot(A.T)).T

# B_scipy != B_hand
```

Why is that? Am I missing something?

Comment: Just how different are they?  `==` test on floats is not reliable.  Use `np.allclose` or just compare values for smallest cases.  To give more help we need a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

@hpaulj is correct. Here's a minimal reproducible example showing the results are element-wise equal to tolerance:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

# Create a random rotation matrix and a random set of points
np.random.seed(0)
R = Rotation.random().as_matrix()
A = np.random.rand(10, 3)

# With scipy
R_scipy = Rotation.from_matrix(R)
B_scipy = R_scipy.apply(A)

# By hand
B_hand = (R.dot(A.T)).T

# B_scipy == B_hand?
print(np.allclose(B_scipy, B_hand)) # Outputs: True
```